# Today's article list - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to list my wordpress today's articles in a short div.
So far, I (think I) have made a proper code to list today's articles but for some reason it says this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in
>   /home/u783756934/public_html/wp-content/themes/wordplus/functions.php
>   on line 30

My code is this:

```
<?php
include "functions.php";

$query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . the_time('Y') . '&monthnum=' . the_time('m') . '&day=' . the_time('d') );
$posts = $query->get_posts();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) 
{ 
  echo($post->post_title);
}

?>
```

My functions.php file is original and unedited.

TLDR:
I need to list articles that have been posted today so I can embed the output on another website.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to run it outside of your theme's core files - it is called without any of the processing WordPress is supposed to do before `add_action()` function. This must be in your theme's functions.php file or within a plugin.
You must add the line `require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');` before the other functions. This should solve your problem.

Also Remember `dirname(__FILE__)` is should point to root WordPress directory, like http://www.yourwebsite.com/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

The functions file behaves like a WordPress Plugin, adding features and functionality to a WordPress site.

You did not require to include it in your theme file. So, remove that first statement (include functions.php) from the code and your code will work fine.

[Funcstion.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) behaviour.